# In at least one object must implement the interface IComparable

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    public class Pokemon
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Weight;
    }


    public class myReverserClass : IComparer
    {

        // Calls CaseInsensitiveComparer.Compare with the parameters reversed.
        int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
        {
            return ((new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare(x, y));
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComparer myComparer = new myReverserClass();

        Random r = new Random();

        string[] pokemons = new string[10];
        pokemons[0] = "Bulbasaur";
        pokemons[1] = "Charmander";
        pokemons[2] = "Squirtle";
        pokemons[3] = "Groulit";
        pokemons[4] = "Caterpie";
        pokemons[5] = "Weedle";
        pokemons[6] = "Kakuna";
        pokemons[7] = "Beedrill";
        pokemons[8] = "Pidgey";
        pokemons[9] = "Rattata";

        string[] sovpad = new string[10];
        Pokemon[] pokemon = new Pokemon[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < pokemons.Length; i++)
        {
            string sovpadtrue;
            sovpadtrue = pokemons[r.Next(0, pokemons.Length)];
            for(int p = 0; p<sovpad.Length;p++)
            {
                if(sovpadtrue == sovpad[p])
                {
                    sovpadtrue = pokemons[r.Next(0, pokemons.Length)];
                    p = -1;
                }
            }
            sovpad[i] = sovpadtrue;
            pokemon[i] = new Pokemon();
            pokemon[i].Name = sovpadtrue;
            pokemon[i].Weight = r.Next(10, 1000);
        }
        Array.Sort(pokemon,myComparer);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

How to add a class myReverserClass, to sort an array of pokemon, first by name, and then the weight?
Error: In at least one object must implement the interface IComparable.
On Msdn example of one-dimensional array only. And myReverserClass taken from msdn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CaseInsensitiveComparer.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.caseinsensitivecomparer.compare.aspx) documentation includes this:

> If a and b are both strings, this method uses CompareInfo.Compare to compare the strings with the casing ignored; otherwise, it uses the IComparable implementation of either object. That is, if a implements IComparable, then this method returns the result of a. CompareTo (b); otherwise, if b implements IComparable, then it returns the negated result of b. CompareTo (a).

and in exceptions:

> ArgumentException: Neither a nor b implements the IComparable interface.

In this case, you're comparing two `Pokemon` objects, and `Pokemon` doesn't implement `IComparable` - hence the exception.

You'd be much better off using the *generic* comparisons, and writing a class which implements `IComparer<Pokemon>`. For example:

```
public class PokemonReverseNameComparer : IComparer<Pokemon>
{
    public int Compare(Pokemon x, Pokemon y)
    {
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(y.Name, x.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that here I *have* actually reversed the argument order - whereas you *claimed* to do so in the comment, but still actually called `Compare(x, y)`. (This doesn't do the weight part though - it's important that you understand one part at a time...)

Personally I'd approach things rather differently, separating out the reversal from the "compare by name" part, and I'd also try to use LINQ, but that's a different matter. LINQ makes it *really* easy - for example:

```
var ordered = pokemon.OrderByDescending(p => p.Name)
                     .ThenBy(p => p.Weight);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jon Skeet's suggestions, you could also do this:

```
Array.Sort(
    pokemon,
    (pokemon1, pokemon2) => {
        // NOTE: Reverse arguments if you want reverse order.
        int result = string.Compare(pokemon1.Name, pokemon2.Name, true);
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        if (pokemon1.Weight < pokemon2.Weight)
            return -1;
        if (pokemon1.Weight > pokemon2.Weight)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
);
```

This sorts the array in-place (unlike LINQ), using `Array.Sort<T>(T[], Comparison<T>)` (instead of the overload that accepts `IComparer`).